# Unable to install Ubuntu on gigabyte 990fxa-ud3 v3.0 motherboard. Error:"unable to find a medium containing a live file system"

Tags: 14.04, boot, 15.04

**unable to find a medium containing a live file system**
Unable to install Ubuntu on **gigabyte 990fxa-ud3 v3.0** motherboard :-( 
I tried with Ubuntu(64b) using Bootable USB stick(Universal-USB-Installer) on both USB 2.0 & 3.0 ports and with following versions:
15.04
14.04.1
14.04.3
12.04.2
Some other posts @ askubuntu suggesting to change legacy mode to UEFI mode also to change from IDE to AHCI, tried both, still stuck with same error.
Please suggest BIOS Settings for this UEFI motherboard...
Solution Please!

> ***FIXED:See Answers(Enable IOMMU)***

Comment: Change IOMMU in BIOS. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2111223&page=5 and:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2292025

Comment: :D Thanks a lot! I changed IOMMU, thats it...its now working like a champ :D Thanks again :)